# How to know which URL failed in curl_multi_exec?

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

I wrote a class to make it easier to use multi cURL requests I want to log errors when I get a 404 error or any other error.
I already have `CURLOPT_FAILONERROR` set to true.

I'm currently using `curl_multi_info_read()`.

and this is my code:

```
$active = null;
    do {
        $multi_exec = curl_multi_exec($this->_multi_handle, $active);
    } while ($multi_exec == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

    while ($active && $multi_exec == CURLM_OK) {
        if (curl_multi_select($this->_multi_handle) != -1) {
            do {
                $multi_exec = curl_multi_exec($this->_multi_handle, $active);
                $info = curl_multi_info_read($this->_multi_handle);
                if ( $info['result'] != 0 ) {
                    $this->_errors[] = $info; // currently storing the whole array
                }
            } while ($multi_exec == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
        }
    }
```

The result on error is an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [msg] => 1
            [result] => 22 // on success this is 0
            [handle] => Resource id #4 // does this help in finding the url if I have the handle ID ?
        )
```

So how can I get the URL where the error happened ? this only gives me the handle resource ID

and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on what you actually need, you can pass this handle to either [curl_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) or [curl_errno](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) function to check for errors, and you can use [curl_getinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) to extract the URL from that handle:

```
curl_getinfo($info['handle'], CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```